# Excel custom calendar function not working properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been creating a weekly calendar in excel for a model that I am working on which will have a value of 1 for weeks in between dates (a start date and an end date) that the user inputs and a zero outside of these dates. As the calendar is a weekly calendar, the function currently compares the date that the user inputs (which could be any date of the year) to the first day of the week (week starting Sunday). **The problem is, the function will only work for input dates that are not on the first four or five days of the month**, so if the user puts say January 1st as the start date the function will not work.

What I am trying to do is make it work for any date.

Currently, the function will calculates the cell value by adding the value of the previous week (so if the date was after the start date but before the end date the previous week would have a value of 1) and then conditional on the following IF statement:

1. If the start date is in the same month as the first day of the current week; AND
2. If the day value of the start date is less than the day value of the first day of the current week + 6 (i.e. the first condition to make sure it is in the same week); AND
3. If the day value of the start date is greater than the day value of the first day of the current week (i.e. the second condition to make sure it is in the same week)

If the IF statement resolves to be TRUE, then it adds 1. The issue is with having a start date in the first few days of the month is that the IF statement doesn't resolve to be true. I think this is because the first day of the current week isn't in the same month.

The following is one example of the function:

```
=AG263+IF(AND(AH$260=MONTH(Assumptions!$B118),DAY(AH$262)+6>=
(DAY(Assumptions!$B118)),DAY(AH$262)
=DAY(Assumptions!$B118)),1,0)+IF(AND(AH$260=MONTH(Assumptions!$B125),
DAY(AH$262)+6>=(DAY(Assumptions!$B125)),DAY(AH$262)<=DAY(Assumptions!$B125))
,-1,0)
```

The second IF statement in the function is for the end date and has the same problem as the start date does.

Would really appreciate any help.

Note: The dates are proper dates. :)

Comment: I think that a screenshot (or file sample) would help describing your problem and desired outcome. I tried using some values but it doesn't seem to work as you describe. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has two functions that should let you bypass your entire check... They are **WEEKDAY** and **WEEKNUM**.

WEEKDAY returns the day of the week, based on when your week starts...

For example, =**WEEKDAY**( **DATE**(2013,9,16), 1) returns 2, because today (Monday) is the 2nd day of the week when the week begins on Sunday.

**WEEKNUM** returns the number of weeks that have passed in the year...

For example, =**WEEKNUM**( **DATE**(2013,9,16), 1) returns 38, because today (Sept 16, 2013) is the 38th week of 2013, if you start counting on Sundays...

Using these checks, you should be able to find the boundaries of the week input by the calendar without all the **IF** checks.

Good luck!